# Drawing a semicircle in 3D with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to make a plot of a torus with a semicircle drawn on its surface. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,
        axis equal,
        view={-37.5}{30}]
            \addplot3[surf,
            shader=interp,
            samples=20,
            domain=0:2*pi,y domain=-pi:pi,
            z buffer=sort]
            ({(1+0.25*cos(deg(x)))*cos(deg(y))}, 
             {(1+0.25*cos(deg(x)))*sin(deg(y))}, 
             {0.25*sin(deg(x))});

            \addplot3[color=black,
            samples=20,
            domain=0:pi,
            line width=2.0pt]
            ({cos(deg(x))}, 
             {sin(deg(x))}, 
             {0.25});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates

[image: torus]

which shows the problem: the semicircle gets closed. I'm not particularly well-versed in `pgfplots` (most of the above is stuff I picked up from examples and plots generated with the Matlab script `matlab2tikz`). Is there an easy way to get the unclosed semicircle I'm after?

---

Just did a quick test: the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,
        axis equal]
            \addplot[color=black,
            samples=20,
            domain=0:pi,
            line width=2.0pt]
            ({cos(deg(x))}, 
             {sin(deg(x))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

shows that this problem doesn't occur in a 2D plot:

[image: semicircle2D]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fix this by using

```
 \addplot3[color=black,
        samples=20,
        domain=0:pi,
        line width=2.0pt,samples y=0]
```

so that the `addplot3` command only plots a curve, not a surface.

[image: screenshot]

Further details can be found in `Section 4.6.9: Parameterized plots` of the `pgfplots` documentation.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer and the reference!

Comment: @Wouter, use `line cap = round` so that the 3D effect is not ruined. `\addplot3[color=blue, samples=20, domain=0:pi, line width=2.0pt,samples y=0, line cap=round]`

Comment: @alfC In my case this was part of a bigger figure in which the endpoints of the semicircle were no longer visible, but thanks for the useful hint anyway!